# st_geometry appears to round floating point numbers

Tags: r, r-sf

I have noticed that after using st_transform, if I view the coordinates using the View() command in RStudio, I see decimal places, but functions such as st_geometry seem to return rounded integer values. I'm concerned that my calculations are going to be incorrect if sf is rounding numbers.

```
library(sf)

x <- tibble(name='location 1',lon=21.0122,lat=52.2297)

pt <- x %>% st_as_sf(coords=c('lon','lat'),crs=4326) %>%
  st_transform(3035)
```

If I print the value of the first coordinate, the result does not have decimal places

```
st_geometry(pt)[[1]][1]
```

[1] 5070109

However if I view the sf object in RStudio, it is clearly a floating point number.

```
pt %>% View
```

| name | geometry |
| --- | --- |
| location 1 | c(5070108.64864491, 3292361.60097363) |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rounding occurs only when printing the result. For example:

```
> sprintf("%.15f", st_geometry(pt)[[1]][1])
[1] "5070108.648660272359848"
```

or

```
> options(digits = 15)
> st_geometry(pt)[[1]][1]
[1] 5070108.64866027
```

Check the argument `digits` in `?options` for more details.